# Anyone know what is wrong here?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

```
BEGIN
OPEN DQC_Cursor1 ; 
LOOP

FETCH DQC_Cursor1 INTO @table_name1 ; 
EXIT when DQC_Cursor1%notfound;
EXEC Incorporate @table_name = @table_name1,
    @historical_table_name = Replace(
        @table_name1,
        'Temp',
        'Historical'
    ) ;

END EXEC;
END LOOP;


CLOSE DQC_Cursor1;
commit;
END;
```

The error messages that i get is as follows. I also getting incorrect syntax near ;, expecting conversation when i hover over the underlined error. I have the stored procedure incorporated already written out. Anyone know what is going wrong here?

```
Incorrect syntax near 'LOOP'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXIT'.
```

Comment: What DB engine are you using?

Comment: Please devise a more meaningful title for your question.  Your code indentation is erratic or exotic; it does not make for easy reading.  It is not obvious that the line numbers in the error messages bear any relationship to the SQL you show -- there isn't a LOOP near line 3, for example.  How does this mismatch occur?

Comment: read guide to creating a cursor http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

Comment: C'mon I'm sure it's not a M$ SQL Server code, you would have an example of cursors in MS SQL Server [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616114/SQL-Server-T-SQL-Tips-Tricks#cursor) buddy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `Incorporate` is a stored procedure you have. As the comments suggest, you're a bit mixed up on your cursor syntax and reading through the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) will help a lot. But in this specific case, try:

```
declare @table_name1 varchar(max);

declare DQC_Cursor1 cursor
for
    select Table_Name
    from TableNames;

open DQC_Cursor1
fetch next from DQC_Cursor1 into @table_name1
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    begin
        exec Incorporate @table_name = @table_name1,
                @historical_table_name = replace(@table_name1,'Temp','Historical')
    end
close DQC_Cursor1;
deallocate DQC_Cursor1;
```